# In a class is a variable not accessable from other thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, windows-phone-7, backgroundworker, code-behind

I have an byte array declared in the header of the class. When I want to access it in the audio event Methode of the microphone the array is NOTHING and not available in this class on this point.

Any idea how to declare the array to get access in the other thread?

Regards

```
Private Class Test1234
Private BufferData(1023) As Byte

Private Sub microphone_BufferReady(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles microphone.BufferReady
        ' Retrieve audio data
        microphone.GetData(Me.BufferData)'<-- Is NOTHING
End Sub
End Class
```

I am asking why Me.BufferData is nothing when I am in the microphone Event. Because it is pre-set on initilizing routine with a size of 1024 Bytes

Comment: Is this a mistype?  You're declaration of `BufferData` is incorrect (it shouldn't say `Me.`) and the `GetData` method is being passed `Me.MicBufferData`.  Notice the difference between `MICBufferData` and `BufferData`. Please clear this up so we can help.

Comment: thanks, yes it was mistyped. I have fixed it. hope its more clear now ;-)

Comment: @Nasenbaer - What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Why Me.BufferData is NOTHING when it comes from Microphone event.

Comment: Show the code that initializes the array. Also show where you hook the event. Is it possible that you hook the event before initializing the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BufferData is never initialized, just declared

BufferData As New Byte(1023)